# Copy the Bson to another variable without changing original?

Tags: c#, .net-core, bson

I want to keep a BsonDocument in variable and temp variable. Which should be using different memory and change in one not affect the other. How do i achieve this. when i change the temp variable , the original one also changed.using c# dotnet core 3.1

```
var obj1 = await db.GetBuildingName(); //from db bsondocuments
var obj2 = await db.HierarchyCatalogues();//from db list of bsondocuments

var tempobj = new BsonDocument();
tempobj = obj1;

BsonArray catlist = new BsonArray();
foreach (var term in obj2) { catlist.Add(term); }

tempobj.Add(new BsonElement("metadata", catlist));
```

when i add the metadata into tempobject it also reflected in obj1

Comment: Because `tempobj` and `obj1` refer to the same instance of a `BsonDocument`. `tempobj.Add()` updates the instance that both `tempobj` and `obj1` refer to. You'll need to make a clone of `obj1`

Comment: ya. obj1 reference is  from database. so i can't call it again

Comment: If you're using MongoDB try either `obj1.Clone()` or `obj1.DeepClone()`

Comment: @phuzi you are right.thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all the reference types, you have to clone the object if you want to have a copy of an instance. `BsonDocument` has implemented two clone method: Clone (shallow clone) and DeepClone. I think you look for DeepClone solution:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;

var tempobj = obj1.DeepClone().ToBsonDocument();
```

Comment: after deep clone it change to bsonvalue

Comment: @junealex There is a `ToBsonDocument` extension method in `MongoDB.Bson` package that can convert any objects to `BsonDocument` . But okay, I will add it to the answer